# CakePHP vendor/ is empty and missing autoload.php

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, xampp, composer-php

I'm trying to do the bookmarker tutorial for CakePHP 3.4. My bookmarker/vendor directory is empty, and missing autoload.php file. I installed XAMPP for OS X 7.1.6, and apache and MySQL seem to work. When I run

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
```

It returns

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- cakephp/cakephp 3.4.9 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.4.* -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.4.0, 3.4.1, 3.4.10, 3.4.2, 3.4.3, 3.4.4, 3.4.5, 3.4.6, 3.4.7, 3.4.8, 3.4.9].
```

I tried [composer dumpautoload command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106575/autoload-php-missing-from-vendor-folder-cakephp-3-0) and [uncommenting extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini file and restarting Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735864/cakephp-3-0-novice-vendor-autoload-php) but it still doesn't work.  I'm not sure if the problem is XAMPP installation or composer or any other settings. My OS version is OS X 10.12.5

Any help is appreciated so much.

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+intl**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! When I run  "root$: sudo pecl install intl ", I got "No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/intl"
install failed" error and I have no idea what I should do. Do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: You have to enable `intl` extentation in you php

Comment: you may have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp

Comment: How can I enable intl extension in my PHP? I checked bin/php-config file and it has a link of extension_dir, so I checked that(.../xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-*** file) as well. Still I have no idea how to enable intl extension. I really appreciate your help!